# Url-Specific 404 Not Found With Traversal Routing

Tags: python, pyramid

We are using the Pyramid framework, and have a custom `404 Not Found` handler:

```
@view_config(request_method='GET', renderer='webapp:templates/pages/404.html', context=HTTPNotFound)
@view_config(request_method='POST', renderer='webapp:templates/pages/404.html', context=HTTPNotFound)
def not_found(self):
    # Various (relatively) heavy-weight thinking occurs
    return {"some_data": some_data}
```

This is fine for catching any POST or GET that is not explicitly handled by the traversal routing. However, there is a certain url pattern (`api/*`) where it would be useful to have a completely different handler that we know can be stripped down to:

```
def not_found(self):
    return {"error_message": "This endpoint is not supported by the api."}
```

However, I can't figure out how to set the `view_config` to only catch `context=HTTPNotFound` within the context of `api/`. Note we are using traversal routing, so, we have an `API` object that is in the traversal routing tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/hooks.html#changing-the-not-found-view) any pyramid application can define multiple Not Found Views if necessary. This means that Not Found Views can carry predicates limiting their applicability.

For common use cases pyramid developers added special hooks. These sample hooks (pyramid >= 1.3) will get you the idea.

```
from pyramid.view import notfound_view_config

@notfound_view_config(request_method='GET')
def notfound_get(request):
    return Response('Not Found during GET, dude', status='404 Not Found')

@notfound_view_config(request_method='POST')
def notfound_post(request):
    return Response('Not Found during POST, dude', status='404 Not Found')

@notfound_view_config(context='.your_package.api_class') 
def notfound_post(request):
    """matches only when traversal returns an object of API class"""
    return Response('Not Found during POST request on API endpoint, dude', status='404 Not Found')
```

For more advanced configuration I recommend using [view configuration predicate arguments](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/viewconfig.html#predicate-arguments).

Comment: Interesting! I hadn't particularly planned to use `@notfound_view_config` because I was specifically trying to catch HTTPNotFound (which it might be possible for another view to throw, yes?). However, when experimenting with this I receive the error: `pyramid.exceptions.ConfigurationError: context may not be used as an argument to add_notfound_view`.

Comment: Next best approach is to try a predicate called 'containment' to match objects  in the lineage of your API object. This is perfectly valid since you use traversal and location-aware resources.

Comment: Just going to underscore that 'location aware resources' was the key here: some of them weren't properly set up and caused a problem. Thanks again!